# Cannot Overload + Operator in Class C++

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the addition operator.

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
class ComplexNumber
{
private:
    int* real;
    int* imag;
public:
    ComplexNumber();
    ~ComplexNumber();
    ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber&);
    ComplexNumber& operator=(const ComplexNumber&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, ComplexNumber&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const ComplexNumber&);
    ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber&);
    friend ComplexNumber operator-(const ComplexNumber&, const ComplexNumber&);
    ComplexNumber operator* (const ComplexNumber&);
    friend ComplexNumber operator /(const ComplexNumber&, const ComplexNumber&);
};
```

```
ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber()
{
    real = new int{ 10 };
    imag = new int{ 10 };
}
```

```
ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator+(const ComplexNumber& a)
{
    ComplexNumber temp;
    temp.real = this->real + a.real;
    temp.imag = this->imag + a.imag;
    return temp;
    
}
```

When I try to compile the code, it gives me an error on a.real and a.imag saying that the expression must have integral or unscoped enum type. What does this mean? Thanks to anyone who helps in advance.

EDIT

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const ComplexNumber& a)
{
    out << *(a.real) << " " << *(a.imag) << "i"; 
    return out;
}
```

```
ComplexNumber  aa, ab, ac;
ac = aa + ab;
std::cout << ac << std::endl;
```

This still outputs 10 and 10i instead of 20 and 20i

EDIT2:

```
ComplexNumber& ComplexNumber::operator=(const ComplexNumber& a)
{
    ComplexNumber temp;
    *(temp.real) = *(a.real);
    *(temp.imag) = *(a.imag);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Why are `real` and `imag` of type `int*` instead of type `int`?

Comment: My professor supplied us with the header file and we have to implement it. That's the only reason lol

Comment: Can you post your implementation of `operator=`?

Comment: Yes, I just added it. Thank you for your help

Comment: @ZachSal You should not use `temp` when doing `operator=`, you need to assign to current object by `*this->real = *a.real;`. Look [at my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64691623/941531).

Comment: Yep, that'll be your issue there. Your `operator=` doesn't actually modify the left hand side of the assignment. it creates and returns a temporary value.

Comment: You are adding two pointers, not what they point to. Adding two pointers is like adding two memory addresses. Not possible. `this->real + a.real`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just dereference your `real`/`imag` pointers by `*` operator, like in code below. Alternatively maybe you just need to store them as plain `int` (e.g. `int real;`) instead of pointers to int.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZTfboIwFMbv@xQnLjEM/8zdAnKz@71DqdU1gZZA2ZYY9urslIJYZOrUaOzX75zzO@1BlucrllJ5aJonIVla7ThE@1IXnGYxGSSheo2gvSzhTWV5yr/fqyzhBTmSvBCfVPOAAL6E1D6gPQ2HpcjoISR5laSCWZeTwnu23p@RCsd6wsyULLWrzbsErggq5wXVqthei9kXgssdlHoXBMI2OkTGsedsLG/nUOMcUeQ5G0u4t4NTisUdDUxHriYjH0Dw4WEGePkfRB0S4ohBMBoMnDlT1UwZbEHyLzNmR3jdQN1NHQ7c5U7tpoVRkeunDbQv6ybRPMttUd/8XHdQvv4Q5SpuVwvw6Xp4JKyvQ@x87ar12WfFtqerQp4VuGhg/lcL2xst@D2lw9UjTUC0mCeK@wYdVKWnL3kAQQtEEfieBXk2ixm@O81wWE3MQjgHwkBzoQSvFzIqpPm3mLgdSpdAE/wwC08ZNkgpHjVNrNIis44Dt/G7lXCeU@cINlivaX4B)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class ComplexNumber
{
private:
    int* real;
    int* imag;
public:
    ComplexNumber();
    ~ComplexNumber() {}
    ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber&);
    ComplexNumber& operator=(const ComplexNumber&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, ComplexNumber&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const ComplexNumber&);
    ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber&);
    friend ComplexNumber operator-(const ComplexNumber&, const ComplexNumber&);
    ComplexNumber operator* (const ComplexNumber&);
    friend ComplexNumber operator /(const ComplexNumber&, const ComplexNumber&);
};

ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber()
{
    real = new int{ 10 };
    imag = new int{ 10 };
}
ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator+(const ComplexNumber& a)
{
    ComplexNumber temp;
    *temp.real = *this->real + *a.real;
    *temp.imag = *this->imag + *a.imag;
    return temp;
    
}
ComplexNumber & ComplexNumber::operator=(const ComplexNumber& a)
{
    *real = *a.real;
    *imag = *a.imag;
    return *this;
    
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const ComplexNumber& a)
{
    out << *(a.real) << " " << *(a.imag) << "i"; 
    return out;
}

int main() {
    ComplexNumber aa, ab, ac;
    ac = aa + ab;
    std::cout << ac << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
20 20i
```

Comment: Oh okay, thank you. Just curious, why do I need to dereference if it's pointing to a new int?

Comment: When I try to add the two class objects in main they don't seem to be adding. Would you mind looking at my edit?

Comment: @ZachSal Regarding first your comment - you need to dereference by `*` always if your type is `int *` and you have this type, no matter how was it initialized you need to use `*` everywhere. Regarding second comment, I'll look into your edits now...

Comment: @ZachSal Probably you implemented `operator=` wrongly, I edited my answer and added all code necessary, it outputs `20 20i` in my code, look at that!